With Vue and useFetch, what is the most concise way to check if request data is available?
I'm using Vue and useFetch. I'm pretty new to these tools. I'm using the composition API, with SFCs.
I'm fetching data using this code :
const products = useFetch(`${URLS.BASE}fetchProducts?productCategoryId=${productCategoryId}`).get().json<any>();

Then in my template section, I find myself doing this to test if my request returned data :
<AppPageTitle v-if="category.data?.value?.category"
                          :title="$t('category.title', { categoryName: category.data.value.category.categoryName })" />

This data?.value? part of the v-if makes me feel I'm missing a simpler way to make sure that I have data when with useFetch. I read about isFetching and isFinisehd but I don't think they can help to simplify this.
With multiple requests, and multiple HTML elements that are rendered only if a request succeeded, it looks a bit cumbersome/not ideal.
Is there a more concise syntax that I could use here ?

This totally depends on API response. It's unknown what "category" is and how it is related to "products". The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Basically more concise way requires to structure data in a way to make it easier to consume. If you don't do this then it's category.data?.value?.category

I was asking about the data?.value? part, which comes from how useFetch works. I'll update my question

First, you probably want to use $fetch rather than the lifecycle hook. First one is indeed safer in general if you're not sure what's the difference. Otherwise, checking if your array/object is populated from the API is a good start aka v-if="category.data" should be good enough already.

@kissu I think you assume I'm using NuxtJS, but I'm not, I'm using https://vueuse.org/core/useFetch/

@FlorianMotteau useFetch isn't glorified fetch, if you don't need additional reactivity features that it provides (you could use baseUrl here), you can do data = await (await fetch(...)).json() directly. If you make a request once, you can await the result https://vueuse.org/core/useFetch/#asynchronous-usage and destructure data the way you need too

ok, I will consider to use fetch only

useFetch comes with events that are emitted when the request fails, or succeed, documented here: https://vueuse.org/core/useFetch/#events.
With that in mind, if you dont want to check if the response has come with the expected data, use the onFetchResponse to create a condition of success, and onFetchError to create a condition of error.
const { onFetchResponse, onFetchError } = useFetch(url)

onFetchResponse((response) => {
  console.log(response.status)
  // Get response here, and extract what you want from it.
})

onFetchError((error) => {
  console.error(error.message)
})

Overall I dont think you can oversimplify your response other than desctructuring your values from the data you received, like:
const { category } = products
const { categoryName } = category?.data?.value?.category

<template v-if="categoryName">
  <AppPageTitle :title="$t('category.title', { categoryName })" />
</template>

